# How to run a single command on different remote machines at a single point of time

Tags: shell-script

I have the following shell script which is running in a loop to trigger a performance test on 3 different machines. I want after the validation of the on 3 machines it will trigger the test at the same time. Just like I am sending a curl command to 3 machines at the same time.

```
#!/bin/sh

IP_Addresses=(192.168.2.33,192.168.2.34,192.168.2.35)

triggerPerformanceTest(){ 
    for iplist in $(echo $IP_Addresses | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
        echo "Validating the health end point in the remote server"    
        HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
        HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
        HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
            if [ $HTTP_STATUS -eq 200  ] && [ $HTTP_BODY = "OK" ]; then
                echo "Success!! it seems the health service is ruuning in the target machine"
                echo "Starting the Jmeter Test"
            else
                echo "The health end point of the nodejs service return exit code 1, let the service start on the remote host"
                sleep 20
                HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
                HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
                HTTP_BODY_NEW=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
                count=2
                echo "Re-validating the health end point in the remote server"
                    while [ $HTTP_STATUS_NEW -ne 200 ] && [ $HTTP_BODY_NEW != "OK" ]
                    do
                        echo "Waiting for the Node-js service to start on the remote server"
                        sleep 5
                        HTTP_RESPONSE_FINAL=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
                        HTTP_STATUS_FINAL=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
                        HTTP_BODY_FINAL=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')

                        count=`expr $count + 1`
                            if [ $count -eq 0 ]
                            then   
                                break
                            else
                                continue
                            fi
                    done
                        echo "Starting the Jmeter Test"
            fi
    done
}

triggerPerformanceTest $IP_Addresses
```

so my plan is to put this three curl command to an array element and call them but now they will be one after another. Is there a way I can trigger them parallel on the 3 machines? Like call the below command at one go

```
curl http://192.168.2.33:9096/triggerPerformanceTest
curl http://192.168.2.34:9096/triggerPerformanceTest
curl http://192.168.2.35:9096/triggerPerformanceTest
```

Or there is wat better way to approach this? what I can think of is implement logic on the target machine which will trigger the test with a delay means the first machine will delay the test by some millisecond and the second one will delayed by lesser millisecond compared to first and third with 0.

Comment: Have you ever run this script? That only gives you _one_ correct IP address, the second one. The first will be `[192.168.2.33` and the last will be `192.168.2.35]`. If you're declaring the IPs manually like that, just declare them directly as you need them: `ips=( 192.168.2.33 192.168.2.34 192.168.2.35 )` and then you cna do `for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do ...`,

Comment: Are the remote machines time-synched (ntp?). You need to start the tests asynchronously anyway (using &) and wait for them. You can rig a prior sleep in each host using sleep delay based on date +%S and a modulus 60 to delay to the next exact minute. Needs careful escapes on quotes to ensure it is evaluated on the remote host, not prematurely in the local system.

Comment: Yeah, mistakenly I have given the `[]`. Let me check with this. Thanks @terdon

Comment: @JYOTIPRAKASHMALLICK but why are you declaring a string instead of an array? You are doing this manually, so just use spaces to separate the entries instead of a comma and you don't need sed. Just like I showed in my previous comment: `ips=( 192.168.2.33 192.168.2.34 192.168.2.35 ); for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do`. Or, even more simply: `ips="192.168.2.33 192.168.2.34 192.168.2.35"; for ip in $ips; do ...` since arrays are not supported by `sh` (sorry, I thought you were using bash)

Comment: @terdon got it, but what about the execution on the remote machine how can I achieve this

Comment: There's no point if you don't fix the errors in your script first. For instance, what is `$HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$((HTTP_STATUS_FINAL))`? Just try executing the script once, you will get loads of error messages that you need to fix.

Comment: @terdon actually I am validating the response on two areas, first is the status code should be 200 and the health point should return 'OK' in the response body. to validating them I have created this two-variable although I am not using them as of now as the validation has been taken care.

Comment: No, my point is that `$var=something` is a syntax error. You want `HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$((HTTP_STATUS_FINAL))` and, unless `HTTP_STATUS_FINAL` is an arithmetic expression, you almost certainly want `HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$HTTP_STATUS_FINAL`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104646/discussion-between-jyoti-prakash-mallick-and-terdon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_Addresses=(192.168.2.33 192.168.2.34 192.168.2.35)

triggerPerformanceTest(){ 
        iplist=$1
        LOG=/tmp/$iplist.log
        echo "Validating the health end point in the remote server"  >> $LOG
        HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
        HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
        HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
            if [ $HTTP_STATUS -eq 200  ] && [ $HTTP_BODY = "OK" ]; then
                echo "Success!! it seems the health service is ruuning in the target machine" >> $LOG
                echo "Starting the Jmeter Test" >> $LOG
            else
                echo "The health end point of the nodejs service return exit code 1, let the service start on the remote host" >> $LOG
                sleep 20
                HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
                HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
                HTTP_BODY_NEW=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
                count=2
                echo "Re-validating the health end point in the remote server" >> $LOG
                    while [ $HTTP_STATUS_NEW -ne 200 ] && [ $HTTP_BODY_NEW != "OK" ]
                    do
                        echo "Waiting for the Node-js service to start on the remote server" >> $LOG
                        sleep 5
                        HTTP_RESPONSE_FINAL=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
                        HTTP_STATUS_FINAL=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
                        HTTP_BODY_FINAL=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
                        $HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$((HTTP_STATUS_FINAL))
                        $HTTP_BODY_NEW=$((HTTP_BODY_FINAL))
                        count=`expr $count + 1`
                            if [ $count -eq 0 ]
                            then   
                                break
                            else
                                continue
                            fi
                    done
                        echo "Starting the Jmeter Test" >> $LOG
            fi
}
for ip in ${IP_Addresses[@]}
do
    triggerPerformanceTest "$ip" &
done
```

Let me know if it works as you expected.

`echo` message will be available at `/tmp/$iplist.log`

(Editing....waiting for OP's reply)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to move the loop out of your function and just run the function in the background:

```
#!/bin/sh


triggerPerformanceTest(){ 
  thisIp=$1
  ## the rest of your tests. Just use $thisIp the way you were using
  ## the $iplist variable.
}

IP_Addresses="192.168.2.33,192.168.2.34,192.168.2.35"
for ip in $IP_Addresses; do
    triggerPerformanceTest "$ip" &
}
```

That will launch the test on each ip and, since you are sending the command to the background with `&`, they will be launched at *almost* the same time. Unless you need millisecond accuracy, that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have accepted an answer. I guess, you can also achieve this by using `parallel` command

```
#!/bin/sh

IP_Addresses=(192.168.2.33,192.168.2.34,192.168.2.35)

triggerPerformanceTest(){ 
    for iplist in $(echo $IP_Addresses | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
        echo "Validating the health end point in the remote server"    
        HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
        HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
        HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
            if [ $HTTP_STATUS -eq 200  ] && [ $HTTP_BODY = "OK" ]; then
                echo "Success!! it seems the health service is ruuning in the target machine"
                echo "Starting the Jmeter Test"
            else
                echo "The health end point of the nodejs service return exit code 1, let the service start on the remote host"
                sleep 20
                HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
                HTTP_STATUS_NEW=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
                HTTP_BODY_NEW=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
                count=2
                echo "Re-validating the health end point in the remote server"
                    while [ $HTTP_STATUS_NEW -ne 200 ] && [ $HTTP_BODY_NEW != "OK" ]
                    do
                        echo "Waiting for the Node-js service to start on the remote server"
                        sleep 5
                        HTTP_RESPONSE_FINAL=$(curl -m 1800 --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X GET http://${iplist}:9096/health)
                        HTTP_STATUS_FINAL=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
                        HTTP_BODY_FINAL=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE_NEW | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')

                        count=`expr $count + 1`
                            if [ $count -eq 0 ]
                            then   
                                break
                            else
                                continue
                            fi
                    done
                        echo "Starting the Jmeter Test"
            fi
    done
}

cat IP_Addresses_file | parallel triggerPerformanceTest {}
```

Assuming you have file named `IP_Addresses_file` containing all IP addresses.